# Apple Watch Remote App

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I was wondering how the Apple Watch Remote app is able to detect swiping gestures and taps on an area that does not look like a button. Is this restricted to Apple only at this time, or is there a way for developers to take advantage of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for now (Jun 1, 2015) before they preview new SDK on the coming up WWDC, it is not available for 3rd party developers. All interactions you currently have on watch are tapping a button or table row, force tapping to show menu, swipe to page horizontally for pagination UI and scroll the entire the screen vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add that kind of gesture recognizers currently in WatchKit. This is only available for Apple-owned apps (Apple Watch Native Apps) at this time.

However, it is always good to wait for WWDC 2015 which takes place in San Francisco (June 8-12) and see the new kits and developing materials.

They will introduce a new WatchKit version that allows you to add gesture recognizers and make native Apple Watch apps without need to have iPhone nearby.